# Typescript correct multiple files usage

Tags: typescript

I have this file structure:

```
project
|
| -- src
|     |
|     |--util
|          |
|          |--StringUtils.ts
|          |--Constants.ts
|
| -- test
      |
      | -- catalog
               |
               | -- issue
                      |
                      | -- myTest.ts
```

And the contents of the files:
StringUtils.ts:

```
module Util {
    export class StringUtils {
        static format(formatString:String, ...replacements:string[]):String {
            return formatString.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
                return typeof replacements[number] != 'undefined'
                    ? replacements[number]
                    : match;
            })
        }
    }
}
```

myTest.ts:

```
import imported = require("../../../src/util/StringUtils");

exports.testSomething = function(test) {

    var testOutput:String = imported.Util.StringUtils.format("{0}, this is a test", "Mofo");

    test.ok(true, "this assertion should pass");
    test.done();
};
```

And when running this with nodeunit, I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'StringUtils' of undefined

How do I correctly reference that file?

Comment: try importing in ES6 style `import {StringUtils} from "../../../src/util/StringUtils";` It could be that you need to remove `module Util` from your StringUtils.ts and leave only the class StringUtils

Comment: Alright, that worked (with the module remove). Post it as an answer

Comment: check the update to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forget about modules and use the import statement of ES6. Your code should then look like this

StringUtils.ts:

```
export class StringUtils {
    static format(formatString:String, ...replacements:string[]):String {
        return formatString.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
            return typeof replacements[number] != 'undefined'
                ? replacements[number]
                : match;
        })
    }
}
```

myTest.ts:

```
import {StringUtils} from "../../../src/util/StringUtils";

exports.testSomething = function(test) {

    var testOutput:String = StringUtils.format("{0}, this is a test", "Mofo");

    test.ok(true, "this assertion should pass");
    test.done();
};
```

EDIT

Actually there is a misunderstanding with modules and namespaces. In the new versions of Typescript what had been called `modules` are now `namespaces`. From the docs:

> A note about terminology: It’s important to note that in TypeScript
>   1.5, the nomenclature has changed. “Internal modules” are now “namespaces”. “External modules” are now simply “modules”, as to align
>   with ECMAScript 2015’s terminology, (namely that module X { is
>   equivalent to the now-preferred namespace X {).

It is recommended to use the approach of ES6 where each file is a module itself, but if you still want to use namespaces to separate your code in files then you need to define your namespace as you defined a module before:

```
namespace Util {
    export class StringUtils {
    .....
```

And then import it wherever you want to use it with the classical:

```
/// <reference path="path.to.file.ts"/>
```